# Iptorrents seeding are not working in uTorrent after download?

Tags: download, utorrent, upload

After finished downloading,it goes inactive. seeding are not working. how do i seed to iptorrents?

[image: 1]

Please help me.

Comment: Please include any relevant information in your post. We are here to help, but we don't want to follow links to get all the information that should be in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's not a full screenshot, but usually what has happened when people complain about a lack of uploading is that you've grabbed a torrent that either no one else wants, or that there are a large number of seeders for a small number of leechers.  In either case, you get little to no upload because someone needs to be downloading the file in order for you to upload.  The torrent appears to be healthy, nothing is blocking it, you just can't force it to upload.  That said, I'm not 100% sure what the [F] means, but it doesn't seem to be generating an error.

Comment: thanks for your reply, now i stopped force start. should i have to change any settings in uTorrent? coz, i cant able to seed any IPtorrent files.

Comment: How many leechers do the files you have have one them?  You do have some upload in uTorrent it looks like, just not much.

Answer (score 0):

In uTorrents preferences, under BitTorrent, make sure DHT and PEX are **not** checked .

That solved it for me